# MVC 5 Dropdownlistfor multiselect value binding in edit view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, dropdownlistfor

I have a select2 multiselect dropdown in edit view. When i try to bind selected values to the dropdown, it fails to bind. Any help appreciated. Please find below code snippets from *.cshtml and *.cs file.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Items, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.ItemsBag, "Value", "Text", Model.ItemsSelected.Select(x => x.Value)), new { @class = "form-control features-segments select2-multiselect-checkbox", multiple = "multiple" })

ViewBag.ItemsBag = db.Items.Select(v => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = v.ItemName,
                Value = v.ItemId.ToString()
            });

ModelVM modelVM = new ModelVM()
            {
                ItemsSelected = SelectedItems.Items.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.ItemName, Value = x.ItemId.ToString() })
            };
```

Items model has below items. The property ItemsSelected is not null and has 3 values in it and ViewBag.ItemsBag is also not null and has all the items from the database. Both of these property are of type SelectListItem with properties Text and Value.

```
public int FeatureId { get; set; }
public string FeatureName { get; set; }
public string ReferenceName { get; set; }
public FeatureSection SectionName { get; set; }//Enum
public FeatureType Type { get; set; }//Enum
public bool DefaultBoolValue { get; set; }
public string DefaultTextValue { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemsSelected { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
```

Comment: Try replace `DropDownListFor` (DDLF) with `ListBoxFor` (LBF), because DDLF always sets `allowMultiple = false` while LBF uses `allowMultiple = true`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanks for your quick suggestion. I tried ListBoxFor also, but dint help.

Comment: Can you show what type of `Items` has in viewmodel? Please explain further how the select element "failed to bind", is it null or only contain single selected value?

Comment: Sorry @TetsuyaYamamoto, I have updated the question. The model items has values(not null) and not even single item is binded in dropdown.

Comment: Well, your problem is the dropdownlist bound to `Items` property that has type of `ICollection<Item>`, which is a complex object and not supported by the helper. Take a look for the answer to find out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have item values provided in `ViewBag` definition like this, which clearly indicates string values:

```
ViewBag.ItemsBag = db.Items.Select(v => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = v.ItemName,
    Value = v.ItemId.ToString() // implies all values are strings
});
```

Then the property to bound with `DropDownListFor`/`ListBox` must have `List<string>` or `string[]` type to be bound properly. Using `ICollection<Item>` will not bound because it is a complex object, while the helper requires value types (numeric types/string) to bound with.

Hence, you must create a property with type `List<string>` first:

```
public List<string> SelectedValues { get; set; }
```

And then use `ListBoxFor` helper with that property instead:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedValues, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.ItemsBag, "Value", "Text", Model.ItemsSelected.Select(x => x.Value)), new { @class = "form-control features-segments select2-multiselect-checkbox", multiple = "multiple" })
```

**Note:**

If `ItemId` property has `int` type (and all values are convertible to `int`), try with `List<int>`/`int[]` type instead of `List<string>`/`string[]`:

```
public List<int> SelectedValues { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code in document ready state of jQuery:

```
var result = [1,3,5];// Array of SelectedValues
$("#DropdownID").val(result); // DropdownID = your multi select dropdown Id
```